# Bootstrap DateTimePicker - Disable dates and times before now (current time)

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm trying to resolve some really strange issue with this datetime picker.
This is my code.

```
$("#dep-date").datetimepicker({ // From-date
    timepicker: true,
    closeOnDateSelect: false,
    closeOnTimeSelect: true,
    initTime: true,
    minDate: 0,
    roundTime: 'ceil',
    onChangeDateTime: function (selectedDate) {
        if (selectedDate != null) {
            $("#ret-date").datetimepicker({           //set 'to' mindate as selected
                minDate: new Date(selectedDate),
            });
            startDate = $("#dep-date").val();
        }
    },
    onClose: function () {
        $("#ret-date").focus();
    }
});
$("#ret-date").datetimepicker({ // TO-date
    timepicker: true,
    closeOnDateSelect: false,
    closeOnTimeSelect: true,
    initTime: true,
    minDate: 0,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        if (selectedDate != null) {
            var endDate = $("#ret-date").val();
            if (startDate > endDate) {
                $("#err").css("display", "block");
                $("#ret-date").val('');
            } else {
                $("#err").css("display", "none");
                $("#dep-date").datetimepicker({
                    maxDate: new Date(selectedDate)   //set 'from' maxdate as selected
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

How can I set a `minTime` property in this code? What I want to achieve is that only for the current day, the times before the current time should be disabled. However, for the remaining days all times should be enabled again. Therefore I cannot use `disabledHours`. Any ideas?

Comment: What does the code output when you run it? You never explained that.

Comment: Issue itself dont knw how to bring that output

Comment: Output should be only for current datetime mintime should work for remaining days should not. For example:2015/07/14 16:30 (today) is current time before 16:30 all disabled if i need to select 2015/07/15 02:30 means it will be disabled so except current date remaining days should be enabled.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely possible, although a bit difficult to achieve.

What you need to do is initialise the `minDate` parameter to midnight of the current day. Then, you bind an event listener to the `dp.change` event and reject any times that are *earlier* than the current time.
When rejecting such a time, you notify the user and reset the DateTimePicker time to the current time. I've created a function to do this:

```
// Argument obj is the used DateTimePicker object
// Argument f is the selected datetime by the user
// Argument n is the current datetime
var checkDate = function (obj, f, n) {
    if (f.getTime() < n.getTime()+60*1000 && !open) {
        open = true;
        $('#message').dialog({
            modal: true,
            position: ['center', 'center'],
            show: 'blind',
            hide: 'blind',
            width: 400,
            dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
            buttons: {
                "I understand. Let me try again": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    obj.data('DateTimePicker').setDate(n);
                    open = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Likewise, you still want to update the `minDate` and `maxDate` parameters upon `dp.change` too. Therefore, combining both checking the time and updating the properties, you would get:

```
jQuery("#startDate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    var f = new Date(e.date);    var n = new Date();
    checkDate(jQuery('#startDate'), f, n);
    jQuery('#endDate').data("DateTimePicker").setMinDate(e.date);
});
jQuery("#endDate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    var f = new Date(e.date);    var n = new Date();
    checkDate(jQuery('#startDate'), f, n);
    jQuery('#startDate').data("DateTimePicker").setMaxDate(e.date);
});
```

This will yield exactly what you are after:

[image]

You can find the full code in the jsFiddle I prepared for you:

## [GO TO THE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7uapxd3s/)

Answer (score 0):

you could also disable an array of dates

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    var dat = new Date(this.valueOf())
    dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
    return dat;
}

function getDates(startDate, stopDate) {
    var dateArray = new Array();
    var currentDate = startDate;
    while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
        dateArray.push( new Date (currentDate) )
        currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
    }
    console.dir(dateArray)
    return dateArray;
}



  to = new Date();
  d = new Date(); 
  x = 96; 
  d.setDate(d.getDate() - x);
  disabledDates= getDates(d,to);


$('#foo').datetimepicker({
    disabledDates:disabledDates,
    format: 'DD.MM.Y',
    viewMode: 'days'
  });
```